# Make a footer with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a bootstrap footer like the one on the bottom of this site http://drantipov.com/ . But I don't need it to be ".container-fluid", I want it be a responsive fixed width container - ".container". I don't want it to be sticky. I just need to know how to make those 3 columns with links. Without the column with the logo. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I've tried doing the .row and .col but they don't work.

Comment: Isn`t this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/vm3m74q1/8/

Comment: Well, kinda. I need there to be tree columns. Left one, center one, and the right one. Every time I try to do "col-md-4", but it doesn't work. Maybe it's because I use Bootstrap v2.3.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fiddle for you, check it out :

http://jsfiddle.net/vm3m74q1/7/

To make the 3 columns you can use bootstrap. You can read more about bootstrap columns here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="row" role="navigation">
        <div class="col-sm-4 center"><p>Content here</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 center"><p>Content here</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 center"><p>Content here</p></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS for center :

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Added a new fiddle for you with bootstrap 2.3.2 : http://jsfiddle.net/vm3m74q1/11/

With bootstrap 2.3.2 you need to use span as a div class (change col-sm-4 with span 4 to get the same effect), like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="row" role="navigation">
        <div class="span4"><p>Content here</p></div>
        <div class="span4"><p>Content here</p></div>
        <div class="span4"><p>Content here</p></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

To delete the spaces between you need to remove margin and change width of .span4, updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vm3m74q1/12/

```
.span4 {
    background: red;
    margin:0;
    width: 33.3%
}

nav {
    margin: 0
}

.row {
    margin:0
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't seem to work. All 3 <p></p> are under each other.

Comment: Updated answer with fiddle for 2.3.2

Comment: That works. Thanks! I see that the code doesn't has any .col-md-4 or anything. Great. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! One more question, though. How can I remove the spaces between the containers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Courtsey of GetBootstrap: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGpPjX

```
 //Needed since no content
 <div id="wrap">
      <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
      }

      #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
        margin: 0 auto -60px;
      }

      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      #push,
      #footer {
        height: 60px;
      }
      #footer {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        #footer {
          margin-left: -20px;
          margin-right: -20px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. But its still not working. I think that I may know the problem, though. Could it be because I'm using Bootstrap v2.3.2? I'm using this version because my website looks compact and small - the way I need this. But when I try to use Bootstrap v3.3.5 - new version - I can't make the design that I need.